# Show Symfony profiler only for admins

Tags: php, symfony

I would like to show the Symfony profiler bar (and access to profiler) only for page admins (ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN).

I have following this instructions: http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/profiler/matchers.html#creating-a-custom-matcher

But there does not work. I get this error message:

```
AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException in classes.php line 2892:
The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL.
```

Can anybody help me, or know this error message?

Thanks for all replies in future!

Comment: could you share the security.yml file ? it seems that the problem is there

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
Here is a pastebin: http://pastebin.com/jJBFixkJ
I have already found the issue. The following lines need to be uncommented:
`firewall:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the `dev` section in your `security.yaml` have the right arguments.

Make sure you uncomment the following lines in your `security.yaml`:

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
```

After there it should working fine.