# Symfony 5 - How to enable profiler in production environment (restricted by user role)

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I'm trying to find a way to enable the symfony profiler in my production environment.

It's also important that the profiler is only accessible when the user has certain roles. To prevent safety issues.

Is this even possible in Symfony 5? I've found an old post for a previous version (2.8) of Symfony here:
[Show Symfony profiler only for admins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37551442/show-symfony-profiler-only-for-admins)

But this method seems to be deprecated.